# Stemming after CollationKeyFilterFactory

Tags: java, solr, localization, stemming, filterfactory

to process non-english text on solr, I use the CollationKeyFilterFactory to change words with local characters into ASCII version of this word.

Like `München` --to--> `Muenchen`.

This is important to handle the specifics of an non-english language.

Example: The words `Volker` (males first name) and `Völker` (means: nations) are stemmed to the same `volk`, although those both words have absolutely different meaning. So the search results will be bad.

For this, special local character have to be transformed, like `ö` to `oe`.
This results to:
`Volker` -> `Volker` and `Völker`-> `Voelker`

How this works is descried here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UnicodeCollation#Searching

After applying the CollationKeyFilterFactory, the `term text` is an binary value, not a string. (see the picture below)

My question: is there a way to stem on the output of CollationKeyFilterFactory?

The analyses output lookes like that:

[image: Solr analyser output with active CollationKeyFilterFactory]